# Changing BLE connection parameters on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

On Android you can use [`requestConnectionPriority()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestConnectionPriority(int)) to very roughly update the connection parameters of a device (they only let you choose fast/normal/low power, but it is better than nothing I suppose).

Is there an equivalent of this function on iOS that lets you do a BLE connection parameter update request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason, no.

You have to do it from the slave side using a L2CAP connection parameter update request.

Comment: Hmm as I suspected. To be honest I was surprised to find the Android function, given [how little of the Bluetooth API Google normally exposes](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58164)!